# Replacing background image javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

Is there a way to change the background-image style with javascript? i currently have:

```
if($(".stLarge").attr.backgroundImage = "http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_32.png") {

      console.log('hello');
      $('.stLarge[backgroundImage="http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_32.png"]').attr("backgroundImage", "url(/images/facebook.png)";
    }
```

It's getting inside the if statement but not executing the image change. Any idea what i have done wrong? Thanks in  advance

Comment: Are you basing your changes on background image to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BackgroundImage` is a property of the `style` object within Element Objects and not an attribute. You can change and read css properties with jQuery [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

```
var imgUrls = ['http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_32.png', '/images/facebook.png']
var $jq = $(".stLarge");
if($jq.css('background-image').indexOf(imgUrls[0]) > -1){
   $jq.css('background-image', 'url("' + imgUrls[1] + '")');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is an atribute backgroundImage, you need to use css

```
$('.stLarge[style*="background-image: url(http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_32.png)"]').css("background-image", "url(/images/facebook.png)");
```

[jQuery - css() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors and misuse of jQuery. Do this:

```
$('.stLarge').each(i, e){
  if($(e).css('backgroundImage').match(/url\(('|")?https?\:\/\/w\.sharethis\.com\/images\/facebook_32\.png(\1)?\)/)){
    $(e).css('backgroundImage', "url('/images/facebook.png')");
  }
}
```